# Array of objects rendered even before certain array functions are finished

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, vue.js, object

As the title says, I have a series of array altering such as `pushing`, `reducing`, and `mapping`.

To start... I have a 2 JSON called `assignee_list` and `ticket_list`. and for some reason, when a condition is met, I need to combine these 2 objects into one.

After I receiver the `ticket_list` from api request. The `_ticketList()` function will then be called. It will look like this.

```
list_array: [] //global variable
  _ticketList() {
        var temp = [];
        var x = 0;
        this.assignee_list.forEach(user => {
           this.ticket_list.forEach(tix => {
               if (user.id == tix.technician_id) { //this is the condition
                   temp.push({
                       technician_id: user.id,
                       name: user.name,
                       data: tix,
                   })
               }
            });
            x++;
    });

    if (x == this.assignee_list.length) {
        var result = Object.values(temp.reduce((r, {technician_id, name, data}) => {
            if (r[technician_id]) {
                r[technician_id].data.push(data);
                r[technician_id].name = name;
                r[technician_id].technician_id = technician_id;
            } else {
                r[technician_id] = { technician_id, name, data: [data]};
            }
        }, {}))
        const resultArray = Object.keys(result).map(i => result[i]);
        this.list_array = resultArray.reverse();
    }
}
```

When I render `list_array` in the front-end, it works. However, It got rendered even before the series of array altering is done. As a result, I have to wait for 10 seconds minimum for all the items to be rendered, worst case: sometimes, it does not render anything at all and needs to refresh the page to render the items again.

Are there any alternatives on the way I achieve the `list_array` without going through a multiple array altering functions? 
Any idea on how I make it optimized as possible?

**Sorry for bad english :))**

Comment: How do you render the list ?

Comment: @Ben using `v-for`